# Find object in child class from object in parent class in django

Tags: django, django-models

Let's say I have a parent class (ThingsThatMigrate) and two children (Coconut and Swallow).  Now let's say I have a ThingsThatMigrate object.  How can I determine if it is in fact a Coconut or a Swallow?  Once having done so, how can I get to the Coconut or Swallow object?

Comment: What's the difference between Coconut and Swallow internally? i.e. any extra fields or methods that one has and the other doesn't?

Comment: extra fields and methods and also different branches of further inheritance

Answer (score 7):

Django doesn't offer such model polymorphism out of the box.The easiest way to do what you are trying to achieve is to store the content type of a new object in it. There's a simple generic app called [django-polymorphic-models](https://code.google.com/p/django-polymorphic-models/) which offers you this functionality - and - additionally a `downcast`-method that will return the child object!

Comment: I used a similar technique for User sub-classes and it works well. Wish I'd known that app existed before.

Comment: I used to use this technique until I discovered a better approach. [django-model-utils' InheritanceManager](https://github.com/carljm/django-model-utils/) does not require the additional content-type field, and can obtain a heterogeneous result set in a single query thanks to the internal `select_related` usage.

Answer (score 2):

Concrete or abstract inheritance? If concrete:

```
>>> things = ThingsThatMigrate.objects.all().select_related('coconut', 'swallow')
>>> for thing in things:
...     thing = thing.coconut or thing.swallow or thing
...     print thing
```

This can be automated using [django-model-utils](https://github.com/carljm/django-model-utils/) `InheritanceManager` (then you don't need to worry about `select_related` or manually listing all possible subclasses). Maintained by another Django core developer.

Comment: But this requires me to know that I'm looking for either a coconut or a swallow - I'm looking for a solution wherein I needn't know the name of the child class.

Comment: That's why I pointed you to `InheritanceManager`, and emphasised how it avoids listing subclasses :)

Comment: I could post a code snippet showing how to introspect the reverse OneToOne relationships to get this information, but you're probably better off either using InheritanceManager, or inspecting its source code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not particularly pretty or efficient, but the best way I can think of implementing this without storing the subclass meta data in the DB (like [django-polymorphic-models](https://code.google.com/p/django-polymorphic-models/) does) would be a `child()` method in your `ThingsThatMigrate` model class:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

def child(self):
    for subclass in self.__class__.__subclasses__():
        try:
            return getattr(self, subclass.__name__.lower())
        except (AttributeError, ObjectDoesNotExist):
            continue
```

Comment: Though depending on where your subclasses are declared and how your import statements are structured, `__subclasses__` may not contain the complete list of subclasses. Introspecting the relationships is safer.

Answer (score 0):

On a Django CMS I work with (Merengue http://www.merengueproject.org/), we store the "classname" attribute that stores what is the real class of the object.

In order to get the real instance we used the following method:

```
    def get_real_instance(self):
        """ get object child instance """
        def get_subclasses(cls):
            subclasses = cls.__subclasses__()
            result = []
            for subclass in subclasses:
                if not subclass._meta.abstract:
                    result.append(subclass)
                else:
                    result += get_subclasses(subclass)
            return result

        if hasattr(self, '_real_instance'):  # try looking in our cache
            return self._real_instance
        subclasses = get_subclasses(self.__class__)
        if not subclasses:  # already real_instance
            self._real_instance = getattr(self, self.class_name, self)
            return self._real_instance
        else:
            subclasses_names = [cls.__name__.lower() for cls in subclasses]
            for subcls_name in subclasses_names:
                if hasattr(self, subcls_name):
                    return getattr(self, subcls_name, self).get_real_instance()
            return self
```

The important thing of this function is that it keeps in mind if the class is abstract or not, wich change the logic a little bit.

Comment: Also suffers from the potentially incomplete `__subclasses__` problem, the necessity of an additional field and more expensive queries than django-model-utils.

Comment: Maybe, django-model-utils does not work properly with multiple inheritance levels. And I really don't get what problem presents __subclasses__

Answer (score 0):

As DrMeer suggested, I highly recommend [django-model-utils](https://bitbucket.org/carljm/django-model-utils/src) (hosted on bitbucket now though). I'm not sure it's convincing enough though.
Let a code example prove it:

```
>>> ThingsThatMigrate.objects.all().select_subclasses()
Coconut, Coconut, Swallow, Coconut, ThingsThatMigrate
```

It takes one line, `objects = InheritanceManager()` in your parent model.

Answer (score -2):

From [the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance):

> If you have a `Place` that is also a `Restaurant`, you can get from the `Place` object to the `Restaurant` object by using the lower-case version of the model name...

Comment: but what if, as I ask in my question, I have a place object and I'm not sure if it's a Restaurant or a Castle?

Comment: The answer to that is in the same place, after the code snippet.

Comment: I have read that doc a number of times of course.  I do not see the reference you are talking about.  Are you talking about the obvious fact that trying a different child from the one that the object is an instance of will raise that class' DoesNotExist?

Comment: If you access `somemodel.coconut` and it throws an exception then it's clearly not a coconut and therefor must be something else.

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  The documentation clearly spells that out.  That's why I have asked the question I have asked, which is - how can I tell what it is?  I didn't ask how I can tell what it's not.  Are you saying that you believe I need to test every child class?

Comment: Yes. Welcome to model inheritance in Django.

Comment: I'm not really feeling the passive aggressive / rude approach.  I'm already very familiar with model inheritance in django.  Somehow I had never come across this problem.  This is a problem.  If you are correct, this is simply a missing important feature.