# Django - Why subclassing auth.User is not recommended for additional information?

Tags: django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Django: Why create a OneToOne to UserProfile instead of subclassing auth.User?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452288/django-why-create-a-onetoone-to-userprofile-instead-of-subclassing-auth-user)

Why subclassing auth.User is not the recommended way for additional information about Users (auth.User), but [creating a UserProfile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's not such a big difference to the [recommended django way](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) as subclass of a model will internally also be connected through a `OneToOneField` to the parent class!