# ModelName(django.contrib.auth.models.User) vs ModelName(models.Model)

Tags: django, django-models, web

I am developing a django project. I created some apps, some of those are related to User model, for instance, I have a feeds app that handles user feeds, and another app that deals with extra user data like age, contacts, and friends. for each of these, I created a table that should be connected to the User model, which I using for storing and authenticating users.

I found two ways to deal with this issue. One, is through extending User model to be like this:

```
ModelName(User):
    friends = models.ManyToMany('self')
    .....
```

Two, is through adding a foreign key to the new table like this:

```
ModelName(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    friends = friends = models.ManyToMany('self')
    ......
```

I can't decide which to use in which case. in other words, what are the core differences between both?

Comment: see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452288/django-why-create-a-onetoone-to-userprofile-instead-of-subclassing-auth-user

Comment: I think this question is what I was searching for

Comment: No, I don't think you were searching at all. This question has *several* duplicates.

Comment: I don't like idea connecting profile model to user via user field because of extra separation one user entity to 2 different models with 2 identificators and bunches of fields. In case of inheriting you just need to override default User module with inherited new one. As result every user will have only one ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either way will technically work. Subclassing the `User` model is effectively the same as subclassing `models.Model` and then including a `user = models.OneToOneField(User)` line.

That said, for what it's worth, the [Django book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter12/#cn222) opts for the `models.Model` route. I also agree that this is syntactically more straightforward.

I would also point you to the [storing additional information about users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) section of the Django documentation, which will teach you about the `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` setting and the `get_profile()` method. It is very much best practice to use those.

Comment: I agree with @Luke, inheriting from the `User` model is not such a good idea. Creating a `UserProfile` model is much better practice. And with `get_profile()`, is as fast as any other solution.

Comment: Inheriting from `User` is a terrible idea. But this answer does not explain *why*.

Comment: I don't see any particular reason why inheriting from `User` is an *intrinsically* terrible idea (Django allows model inheritance for a reason). I just think it's always better to follow the framework's published best practice, and in this case, there is already a Django way to do *exactly* what the OP wants.

Comment: I don't like idea connecting profile model to user via `user` field because of extra separation one user entity to 2 different models with 2 identificators and bunches of fields. In case of inheriting you just need to override default User module with inherited new one. As result every user will have only one ID.