# Correctly accessing derived class in OneToOneField relation in Django-Nonrel

Tags: django, django-models, django-nonrel

I'm pulling my hair out trying to solve this (hopefully) simple problem.

I am using Django-nonrel, and I am trying to setup a few models. I've simplified the code below:

```
class Application(models.Model)
    name = "Application"

    def get_name(self):
        print(self.name)

class ExampleApp(Application)
    name = "Example Application"

class Site(models.Model)
    app = models.OneToOneField(Application, null=True)
    id  = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    # other details not important
```

When I obtain an instance of `Site`, I would like to obtain an instance of the derived class (e.g. `ExampleApp`)

```
class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Presuppose that I have an object with id="a"
        site = Site.objects.filter(id="a")

        #<Application: Application>
        app = site.app

        #returns "Application", not "Example Application"
        app.get_name()
```

**How can I access the derived class?**

*(Ideally, I would like `Application` to be an abstract base class, but django does not allow relationships to abstract base classes. I would define fields inside `Application`, but django-nonrel does not support multi-table inheritance.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Furbeenator answered is correct, but I feel that my (self-)answer could be more valuable to anyone in my situation.

`Django-nonrel` includes a few nice apps, notable `djangotoolbox`. Included in `djangotoolbox` is a particular field, `EmbeddedModelField`. It appears to store a copy of a model as a blob in the 'container' model.

In my example:

```
from djangotoolbox.fields import EmbeddedModelField

class Site(models.Model)
    app = EmbeddedModelField(null=True)
    id  = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    # other details not important
```

The upside to this is that, in my circumstances, it also meant that I could make my `Application` class abstract. The downside is that the data is now duplicated, and I still cannot access the `Site` instance from the `Application` instance (but in my case, that was an acceptable tradeoff).

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, without additional Django plugins. See [Find object in child class from object in parent class in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348157/find-object-in-child-class-from-object-in-parent-class-in-django), where the answer by lazerscience suggests using https://code.google.com/p/django-polymorphic-models/ to access this functionality.

Comment: That certainly *looks* like what I'm interested in. Any idea as to whether or not this works in Django-nonrel?

Comment: I haven't tried it out, but I would imagine it would work with djanog-nonrel, which is just an implementation with NoSQL, this should be irrelevant of the NoSQL support.

Comment: The solution doesn't quite apply to the current circumstances. Polymorphic models don't appear to do anything special when referring to relations. Also, if I make the base class a PolymorphicMetaClass, I get an error when I try to downcast: `Multi-table inheritance is not supported by non-relational DBs.`