# Django: To combine and retrieve rows from different models

Tags: django

1.We have two similar models, and
I would like to be able to retrieve these at the same time and sort them by posting date and time, etc.
Is it possible?

2.Or should both redundant fields be combined into one model?

```py
# 1.
class Model1(models.Model):
    title = ...
    thumbnail = ...
    description = ...
    ...

class Model2(models.Model):
    title = ...
    image_url = ...
    product_id = ...
    reivew = ...


# 2. Combine into one model
class Model(models.Model)
    title = ...
    thumbnail = ...
    description = ...
    image_url = ...
    product_id = ...
    reivew = ...
```

Comment: Can you please explain, what is relation between `Model1` and `Model2`? Are you forced to separate two models?

Comment: They're both video models, but one is a user-submitted video and the other is a product introduction video, so the fields are quite different, but we need to handle both, with view history, playlists, etc., because we'd rather have one model, so... If so, that is also acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

You can union() two models with no shared parents, and after that order_by() some
column.

Comment: Can a .union get both of its different fields even if the fields in the two models are different?

Comment: yes, you can use values_list() and select some field of each model.

Comment: Can you show us a sample of what the code will look like?

Answer (score 0):

'Consider this answer from a beginner'
If you just want to fetch someones `model1` and `model2` objects with just one query statement maybe is good to inherit two models from a base model like this:
in your `models.py`:

```
class Base(models.Model):
    title = ...
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(user)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at'] 

# inherits fields of Base model
class Model1(Base):
    field = ...
    # fields

class Model2(Base):
    # fields
```

using this method, remember fill needed fields of `Base' model like this:

```
>>> m1 = Model1(field="value", title=..., owner=UserObject,...).save()
# for get objects do normal:
>>> objects = Base.objects.filter(owner=user)
# the result is list of users `Model1' or 'Model2` created objects
```

Also you can use [django-model-utils](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and get `Base` objects by child type. It would be like this:

```
from model_utils.managers import InheritanceManager
 
class Base(models.Model):
    # like previous version
    # just remember modify objects
    objects = InheritanceManager()

# inherits fields of Base model
class Model1(Base):
    
class Model2(Base):
```

get objects:

```
>>> Base.objects.all().select_related('Model1', 'Model2')
```

please read also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5466626/18129097) and others.